# How do you find the coefficient values for the unique causal solution of $\text{AR}(p)$?

Tags: time-series, arima, causality, autoregressive

I am working with a causal $\text{AR}(p)$ model.  I know I can express this in causal form as:

$$X_t = \psi(B) W_t
\quad \quad \quad
\psi(z) = \theta(z)/\phi(z).$$

I also know that the parameters are related by the polynomial equation

$$(1 − \phi_1 z− \cdots − \phi_p z^p) (\psi_0 + \psi_1 z + \cdots) = 1 + \theta_1 z + \cdots + \theta_q z^q,$$

which gives the first few values:

$$\begin{aligned}
\psi_0 &= 1 \\[6pt]
\psi_1 &= \theta_1 + \psi_0 \phi_1 \\[6pt]
\psi_2 &= \theta_2 + \psi_1 \phi_1 + \psi_0 \phi_2 \\[6pt]
\end{aligned}$$

To get the general form of the $\psi_j$ values, I understand that I am supposed to equate the coefficients of $z^j$ on both sides for $j = 0,1,2,...$, but I'm still confused on how to do so.  Could someone help walk me through as to how to get the values of all the $\psi_j$ coefficients?

Comment: Your second equation has $\psi(z)$ on both sides...

Comment: Thank you - it's been edited